# Do the vectors $u, v$ and $w$ span the vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> if $V=\mathbb{R}^3=\lbrace (a,b,c)\ | \ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$, we know that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ under the componentwise addition and scalar multiplication. Show that the vectors $(1,-1,2), \ (1,3,1), \ (1,2,1)$ span $V$.

My attempt:

Let $u=(1,-1,2), \ v=(1,3,1), \ w=(1,2,1)$

we say that $u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$ if every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as a linear combination of $u, v, w$.

let $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if we find $\alpha_1,\ \alpha_2, \ \alpha_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, satisfying that;

$(a,b,c)=\alpha_1 u+ \alpha_2 v+ \alpha_3 w$

Then $u,v$ and $w$ span $V$.

Now,

$(a,b,c)=\alpha_1 (1,-1,2)+ \alpha_2 (1,3,1)+ \alpha_3 (1,2,1)$

This implies that,

$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=a$

$-\alpha_1+3\alpha_2+2\alpha_3=b$

$2\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=c$

And by solving this system, we find that;

$\alpha_1=c-a$

$\alpha_2=-5a+b+3c$

$\alpha_3=7a-b-4c$

This show that any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear combination of $(1,-1,2), \ (1,3,1), \ (1,2,1)$, hence the vectors $(1,-1,2), \ (1,3,1), \ (1,2,1)$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$

Is that true 100% ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

You have proved the statement clearly and correctly.

You could have checked the determinant made by your three vectors and show that the determinant is non zero.